# Insert "Copy" button in pdf

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, documents

I want to add a button to a pdf that will copy some text to clipboard when clicked. Is it possible? If yes, how? I'm using LibreOffice Writer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LibreOffice Basic macro for this and add a button:

```
Sub Main
    Dim strClipTxt,WshShell
    strClipTxt = InputBox("Please enter some text to add to clipboard:","Copy to clipboard")
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run("cmd /c echo " & strClipTxt & " | clip",0,True)
    ' Next line is omittable, to make silent
    MsgBox("Copying was successful!",64,"Copy to clipboard")
End Sub
```

This will work in Windows environment, uses `clip.exe` to add text to clipboard. It will prompt an input box to enter the text to add to clipboard, and then add it to clipboard. Another way is to add the selection in Document to clipboard:

```
Sub Main
    Dim WshShell
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run("cmd /c echo " & ThisComponent.CurrentSelection.getByIndex(0).String & " | clip",0,True)
End Sub
```

This will add the Current Selection to clipboard.

[Docs on adding button and other form controls in Document - LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/he/text/shared/guide/formfields.html)

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem: The text I want to copy isn't English; it's Persian and because of this, this solution isn't good for me.